# How to handle response .json and .text using fetch?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, fetch-api

I'm fetching an API that returns a json but when it has an error, it returns only a text (In node with express, results are returned with `.json({})` and errors with `.send('string')`), but **I can't modify the API**.

So I'm trying to make something that reads the json, but if it's an text, it will go in `.catch` where the error is the text.

Here is what I have tried but with no success:

```
fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(res => {
        try {
            let json = res.json()
            return json
        } catch (error) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(res.text()))
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        // get result from res.json() **res == res.json**
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // get result from res.text() **res == res.text**
    })
```

How can I achieve this? How to get `res.json()` in the next `.then()` but if it fails, get `res.text()` in the `.catch`?

**Edit**: I want to get the `.text` in `.catch`. I don't know why, but throwing `res.text()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 18):

Another approach would be to simply format eveyrthing to text initially and only then try to parse it, while throwing an error in case of parsing issues.

```js
fetch("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=google")
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body => {
        try {
            return JSON.parse(body);
        } catch {
            throw Error(body);
        }
    })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);

fetch("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=google")
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body => {
        try {
            return JSON.parse(body);
        } catch {
            throw Error(body);
        }
    })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: I like this solution.

Answer (score 14):

Ideally, your client application should **know** what response kind to expect and have static code that calls the appropriate method.

---

Another way to deal with your situation is to inspect the response `contentType` and call `.json()` or `.text()` depending on particular response header value.

```
handleResponseStatusAndContentType(response) {
  const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type')!;

  if (response.status === 401) throw new Error('Request was not authorized.');

  if (contentType === null) return Promise.resolve(null);
  else if (contentType.startsWith('application/json;')) return response.json();
  else if (contentType.startsWith('text/plain;')) return response.text();
  else throw new Error(`Unsupported response content-type: ${contentType}`);
}
```

Usage:

```
return fetch(
  url,
  requestInit,
)
.then(response => handleResponseStatusAndContentType(response))
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
  return error;
});
```

Comment: What is that syntax around the new Promise? It looks like templating/generics, but JS doesn't have that.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk apologies. That was a piece that I missed when translated my TypeScript code into JavaScript...

Comment: Just realised that this isn't correct. If it's only a text, it will go in the next `.then` but not in the `.catch`

Comment: @Vencovsky not sure what you mean.

Comment: returning a promise resolving to null in your code: `new Promise(() => null)` is not correct, as it will just return a promise that will never resolve, instead try `Promise.resolve(null)`

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Corrected. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

A workaround that makes the code for handling this much simpler is to clone the response to get around only being able to read it once:

`fetch(apiUrl).then(res => res.clone().json().catch(() => res.text()))`

Answer (score 0):

The static `JSON.parse` method will natively throw an error if it is unable to parse the argument given, so we can use that to our advantage to throw the result of the `text` method being invoked on the response to be caught further down the promise chain.

So pretty close, just a little bit off.

#### Usage

```js
fetch(apiUrl)
  .then(async (response) => {
    const text = await response.text();

    try {
      return JSON.parse(text);
    } catch (err) {
      throw text;
    }
  })
  .then((json) => {
    // Handle the result of the response being parsed as JSON
  })
  .catch((text) => {
    // Handle the result of the response being parsed as text
  });
```

Comment: This can be costly if the responses are big or if there are a lot of requests at the same time. Duplicating objects in memory just to follow some logic is not very efficient.